# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression using jquery to load a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>user/profile"><?php echo System::translate("Profile"); ?></a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>user/edit_profile" ><?php echo System::translate("Personal information"); ?></a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>training/basket"><?php echo System::translate("Training basket"); ?></a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>invoice/all"><?php echo System::translate("Invoices"); ?></a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>favourite/favourites" data-target="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>favourite/favourites"><?php echo System::translate("Favourites"); ?></a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>user/preferences"><?php echo System::translate('Preferences'); ?></a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>user/update_password"><?php echo System::translate('Update password'); ?></a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>notification/all"><?php echo System::translate('Notifications'); ?> <span class="label label-danger pull-right"><?php echo System::escape(count($notifications_all)); ?></span></a></li> 
                </div>
```

I am loading them up with ajax to populate, but whenever I click a link I get an error in my console saying unrecognized expression, my jquery to load the content:

```
$('.list-link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type:'GET',
        headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
        success: function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

I've added a data-target but still get the console error, what is causing this, and how could I fix this?

rendered html:

```
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a class="list-group-item" href="http://localhost/user/profile">Profile</a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="http://localhost/user/edit_profile" >Personal information</a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="http://localhost/training/basket">Training basket</a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="http://localhost/invoice/all">Invoices</a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="http://localhost/favourite/favourites" data-target="http://localhost/favourite/favourites">Favourites</a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="http://localhost/user/preferences">Preferences</a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="http://localhost/user/update_password">Update password</a></li>
                    <a class="list-group-item list-link" data-toggle="tab" href="http://localhost/notification/all">Notifications <span class="label label-danger pull-right">0</span></a></li> 
                </div>
```

error lines:

```
at.error    @   jquery.min.js:4
bt  @   jquery.min.js:4
At  @   jquery.min.js:4
at  @   jquery.min.js:4
x.fn.extend.find    @   jquery.min.js:5
x.fn.x.init @   jquery.min.js:4
x   @   jquery.min.js:4
b.show  @   bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function)    @   bootstrap.min.js:6
x.extend.each   @   jquery.min.js:4
x.fn.x.each @   jquery.min.js:4
a.fn.tab    @   bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous function)    @   bootstrap.min.js:6
x.event.dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:5
v.handle    @   jquery.min.js:5
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?  What is the "unrecognized expression"?

Comment: All it says in unrecognized error, then the tab link and the file is jquery.min line 4

Comment: Also show the rendered content. For example quotes or newlines in the PHP will break the script

Comment: I just goot the following error: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.